# C++ - When escaping a double quote it appends the backlash too

Tags: c++, xcode

[image: screenshot from the debugger in XCode]

Why is appending the backslash too? 
If I dont use the backslash for escaping the doble quote, the compiler obviously complains, but if I try to escape the double quote it appends the backslash too.

Am I wrong using the \" in a string?

Comment: This is just the debugger's view. The string doesn't contain the backslash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by king_nak:

> This is just the debugger's view. The string doesn't contain the backslash.

The debugger tries to display the string in C++ format, not in text format. The idea is, you can copy what the debugger shows to you, paste it into a C++ program, and it will work as expected. If the debugger didn't escape the quotes, it would generate a syntax error.

So everything is OK, you are using the escape character correctly.

Comment: True! Just printed it in the console... Another half hour of my life wasted :D Who doesnt love to look for errors that dont exist. Ty King Nak and Anatolyg ;)